# Pandas Sequebtial Count of members within a group and the sum

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

If I want to have a sequential count within a group I can do something like

```
df['GID'] = df.groupby(['G_COL1','G_COL2]).cumcount()
```

I cannot however figure out how to generate a column that contains the total number of values within the group. So if the group had three members df['GID'] would contain 0,1 & 2 and df['COUNT'] would contain the value 3 for each of the three members

Comment: use `.transform('count')`

Comment: Exactly the answer I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
df["count_zeros"] = pd.DataFrame((df["GID"]==0)).cumsum()
df["COUNT"] = df.groupby("count_zeros").transform(lambda x: len(x))["GID"]
```

I think the above gives what you want. The GID column starts from zero whenever a new group starts taking place and then we count how many zeros, i.e. new group "starts" we have with len.

As Scott Boston, commented,

```
df["COUNT"] = df.groupby("count_zeros")['GID'].transform('count')
```

works and looks great :)

Comment: Try: `df["COUNT"] = df.groupby("count_zeros")['GID'].transform('count')`

Comment: That's a beautiful suggestion. Thanks!